# which() and match() functions can't find matches in my numeric vector

Tags: r

I have a numeric vector of 254 elements called smoothed_auto:

```
smoothed_auto
  [1] 0.4167147 0.4168202 0.4169259 0.4170314 0.4171361 0.4172395 0.4173410 0.4174401 0.4175435 0.4176561 0.4177743
 [12] 0.4178945 0.4180133 0.4181271 0.4182322 0.4183252 0.4184301 0.4185647 0.4187166 0.4188734 0.4190225 0.4191516
 [23] 0.4192480 0.4192995 0.4193022 0.4192707 0.4192201 0.4191651 0.4191207 0.4191017 0.4191231 0.4191997 0.4192655
```

(...)

And I am trying to find the indices of specific elements with the which() and match() functions:

```
which(smoothed_auto == 0.4167147)
#integer(0)

match(c(0.4167147), smoothed_auto)
#[1] NA
```

I have tried this with multiple elements and always get the same result. Any help?

Comment: Try `which(round(smoothed_auto, 2) == 0.42)`

Comment: The best way of making it reproducible is to post the output of `dput(smoothed_auto)`, like this the error doesn't occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f) and a duplicate of [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal).

A way of solving it is with a function I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50569202/8245406).

```
are.equal <- function(x, y, tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.5) abs(x - y) < tol

which(are.equal(smoothed_auto, 0.4167147))
#[1] 1
```

**Data**

```
smoothed_auto <- scan(text = "
0.4167147 0.4168202 0.4169259 0.4170314 0.4171361 0.4172395 0.4173410 0.4174401 0.4175435 0.4176561 0.4177743
0.4178945 0.4180133 0.4181271 0.4182322 0.4183252 0.4184301 0.4185647 0.4187166 0.4188734 0.4190225 0.4191516
0.4192480 0.4192995 0.4193022 0.4192707 0.4192201 0.4191651 0.4191207 0.4191017 0.4191231 0.4191997 0.4192655
")
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Apparently, the numbers were rounded in the original vector (smoothed_auto was the output of a function, not a vector I created myself). That seems to be the source of the problem. Using the values from dput(), it works.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `c` in `match(c(0.4167147), smoothed_auto)`

```
smoothed_auto <- as.vector(c(0.4167147, 0.4168202, 0.4169259, 0.4170314, 0.4171361, 0.4172395, 
  0.4173410, 0.4174401, 0.4175435, 0.4176561, 0.4177743, 0.4178945, 
  0.4180133, 0.4181271, 0.4182322, 0.4183252, 0.4184301, 0.4185647, 
  0.4187166, 0.4188734, 0.4190225, 0.4191516, 0.4192480, 0.4192995, 
  0.4193022, 0.4192707, 0.4192201, 0.4191651, 0.4191207, 0.4191017, 
  0.4191231, 0.4191997, 0.4192655))

which(smoothed_auto == 0.4167147)

match(0.4167147, smoothed_auto)
```

Output:

```
> smoothed_auto <- as.vector(c(0.4167147, 0.4168202, 0.4169259, 0.4170314, 0.4171361, 0.4172395, 
+   0.4173410, 0.4174401, 0.4175435, 0.4176561, 0.4177743, 0.4178945, 
+   0.4180133, 0.4181271, 0.4182322, 0.4183252, 0.4184301, 0.4185647, 
+   0.4187166, 0.4188734, 0.4190225, 0.4191516, 0.4192480, 0.4192995, 
+   0.4193022, 0.4192707, 0.4192201, 0.4191651, 0.4191207, 0.4191017, 
+   0.4191231, 0.4191997, 0.4192655))
> which(smoothed_auto == 0.4167147)
[1] 1
> match(0.4167147, smoothed_auto)
[1] 1
```