# R numeric subtraction and comparison produce inconsistent results

Tags: r, numeric

I just notice the error with **numeric subtraction** in R today. It is unbelievable. The reproducible example is simple and complex, just like below. ps. I did not change any `option()` in my R session.

```
> 8.2-0.1==8.1
[1] TRUE
> 8.3-0.1==8.2
[1] FALSE
```

I also test the subtraction results with `dput()`, and it look correct. However, the comparison with the correct value shows false.

```
> a=8.3-0.1
> a%>%dput()
8.2
> a==0.2
[1] FALSE
```

Sometimes even the results of the subtraction is deviated and of course in the case the comparision results in false.

```
> a=8.2-8.1
> a%>%dput()
0.0999999999999996
> a==0.1
[1] FALSE
```

How could this happen and be allowed to remain?

Comment: My [answer to another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50569202/8245406) might be related to this question. Your 2nd example returns true: `are.equal(8.3-0.1, 8.2)`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this happens because your calculations are done in a *digital* computer and not all real numbers can be exactly expressed in digital computer. See R FAQ https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f